# How to modify non-zero elements of a large sparse matrix based on a second sparse matrix in R

Tags: r, performance, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have two large sparse matrices (about 41,000 x 55,000 in size). The density of nonzero elements is around 10%. They both have the same row index and column index for nonzero elements.

I now want to modify the values in the first sparse matrix if values in the second matrix are below a certain threshold.

```
library(Matrix)

# Generating the example matrices.
set.seed(42)

# Rows with values.
i <- sample(1:41000, 227000000, replace = TRUE)
# Columns with values.
j <- sample(1:55000, 227000000, replace = TRUE)

# Values for the first matrix.
x1 <- runif(227000000)
# Values for the second matrix.
x2 <- sample(1:3, 227000000, replace = TRUE)

# Constructing the matrices.
m1 <- sparseMatrix(i = i, j = j, x = x1)
m2 <- sparseMatrix(i = i, j = j, x = x2)
```

I now get the rows, columns and values from the first matrix in a new matrix. This way, I can simply subset them and only the ones I am interested in remain.

```
# Getting the positions and values from the matrices.
position_matrix_from_m1 <- rbind(i = m1@i, j = summary(m1)$j, x = m1@x)
position_matrix_from_m2 <- rbind(i = m2@i, j = summary(m2)$j, x = m2@x)

# Subsetting to get the elements of interest.
position_matrix_from_m1 <- position_matrix_from_m1[,position_matrix_from_m1[3,] > 0 & position_matrix_from_m1[3,] < 0.05]

# We add 1 to the values, since the sparse matrix is 0-based.
position_matrix_from_m1[1,] <- position_matrix_from_m1[1,] + 1
position_matrix_from_m1[2,] <- position_matrix_from_m1[2,] + 1
```

Now I am getting into trouble. Overwriting the values in the second matrix takes too long. I let it run for several hours and it did not finish.

```
# This takes hours.
m2[position_matrix_from_m1[1,], position_matrix_from_m1[2,]] <- 1
m1[position_matrix_from_m1[1,], position_matrix_from_m1[2,]] <- 0
```

I thought about pasting the row and column information together. Then I have a unique identifier for each value. This also takes too long and is probably just very bad practice.

```
# We would get the unique identifiers after the subsetting.
m1_identifiers <- paste0(position_matrix_from_m1[1,], "_", position_matrix_from_m1[2,])
m2_identifiers <- paste0(position_matrix_from_m2[1,], "_", position_matrix_from_m2[2,])

# Now, I could use which and get the position of the values I want to change.
# This also uses to much memory. 
m2_identifiers_of_interest <- which(m2_identifiers %in% m1_identifiers)

# Then I would modify the x values in the position_matrix_from_m2 matrix and overwrite m2@x in the sparse matrix object.
```

Is there a fundamental error in my approach? What should I do to run this efficiently?

Comment: what is `m1@i` achieving?

Comment: m1@i contains the rows that are non-zero, summary(m1)$j are the columns and x are the actual values.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Your solution works very well. But I forgot to add one critical detail.
The order of the i and j elements in the sparse matrices are different. 
So m1@i is not equal to m2@i. This means, that I cannot simply overwrite the values.
The solution using the ij matrix works well enough though. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a fundamental error in my approach?

Yes. Here it is.

```
# This takes hours.
m2[position_matrix_from_m1[1,], position_matrix_from_m1[2,]] <- 1
m1[position_matrix_from_m1[1,], position_matrix_from_m1[2,]] <- 0
```

Syntax as `mat[rn, cn]` (whether `mat` is a dense or sparse matrix) is selecting all rows in `rn` and all columns in `cn`. So you get a `length(rn)` x `length(cn)` matrix. Here is a small example:

```
A <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    4    7
#[2,]    2    5    8
#[3,]    3    6    9
rn <- 1:2
cn <- 2:3
A[rn, cn]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    4    7
#[2,]    5    8
```

What you intend to do is to select `(rc[1], cn[1])`, `(rc[2], cn[2])` ..., only. The correct syntax is then `mat[cbind(rn, cn)]`. Here is a demo:

```
A[cbind(rn, cn)]
#[1] 4 8
```

So you need to fix your code to:

```
m2[cbind(position_matrix_from_m1[1,], position_matrix_from_m1[2,])] <- 1
m1[cbind(position_matrix_from_m1[1,], position_matrix_from_m1[2,])] <- 0
```

Oh wait... Based on your construction of `position_matrix_from_m1`, this is just

```
ij <- t(position_matrix_from_m1[1:2, ])
m2[ij] <- 1
m1[ij] <- 0
```

---

**Now, let me explain how you can do better.** You have underused `summary()`. It returns a 3-column data frame, giving (i, j, x) triplet, where both `i` and `j` are index starting from 1. You could have worked with this nice output directly, as follows:

```
# Getting (i, j, x) triplet (stored as a data.frame) for both `m1` and `m2`
position_matrix_from_m1 <- summary(m1)
# you never seem to use `position_matrix_from_m2` so I skip it

# Subsetting to get the elements of interest.
position_matrix_from_m1 <- subset(position_matrix_from_m1, x > 0 & x < 0.05)
```

Now you can do:

```
ij <- as.matrix(position_matrix_from_m1[, 1:2])
m2[ij] <- 1
m1[ij] <- 0
```

---

**Is there a even better solution? Yes!** Note that nonzero elements in `m1` and `m2` are located in the same positions. So basically, you just need to change `m2@x` according to `m1@x`.

```
ind <- m1@x > 0 & m1@x < 0.05
m2@x[ind] <- 1
m1@x[ind] <- 0
```

---

**A complete R session**

I don't have enough RAM to create your large matrix, so I reduced your problem size a little bit for testing. Everything worked smoothly.

```
library(Matrix)
# Generating the example matrices.
set.seed(42)

## reduce problem size to what my laptop can bear with
squeeze <- 0.1

# Rows with values.
i <- sample(1:(41000 * squeeze), 227000000 * squeeze ^ 2, replace = TRUE)
# Columns with values.
j <- sample(1:(55000 * squeeze), 227000000 * squeeze ^ 2, replace = TRUE)

# Values for the first matrix.
x1 <- runif(227000000 * squeeze ^ 2)
# Values for the second matrix.
x2 <- sample(1:3, 227000000 * squeeze ^ 2, replace = TRUE)

# Constructing the matrices.
m1 <- sparseMatrix(i = i, j = j, x = x1)
m2 <- sparseMatrix(i = i, j = j, x = x2)

## give me more usable RAM
rm(i, j, x1, x2)
```

```
##
## fix to your code
##

m1a <- m1
m2a <- m2

# Getting (i, j, x) triplet (stored as a data.frame) for both `m1` and `m2`
position_matrix_from_m1 <- summary(m1)

# Subsetting to get the elements of interest.
position_matrix_from_m1 <- subset(position_matrix_from_m1, x > 0 & x < 0.05)

ij <- as.matrix(position_matrix_from_m1[, 1:2])
m2a[ij] <- 1
m1a[ij] <- 0

##
## the best solution
##

m1b <- m1
m2b <- m2

ind <- m1@x > 0 & m1@x < 0.05
m2b@x[ind] <- 1
m1b@x[ind] <- 0
```

```
##
## they are identical
##
all.equal(m1a, m1b)
#[1] TRUE
all.equal(m2a, m2b)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

**Caveat:**

I know that some people may propose

```
m1c <- m1
m2c <- m2

logi <- m1 > 0 & m1 < 0.05
m2c[logi] <- 1
m1c[logi] <- 0
```

It looks completely natural in **R**'s syntax. But trust me, it is extremely slow for large matrices.